# InfluxDB invalid field format error while using curl command

Tags: curl, influxdb

I am new to Influx DB

I have to insert the following data to my local influx DB using curl command

```
test_aggregate,processor=name,env=test_env,workspace=test_job_name,area=test_area,test-suite=test_name,build-id=test_build_no,test-name=test_uc_no,step-index=1,step-execution-time=1,step-error-message=No message,test-result=1 1572915987025
```

I am using following curl command

```
curl -i -X POST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=test_db_local&amp;precision=s" --header "Authorization: Token maha:jhdasdaak" --data-binary 'test_aggregate,processor=name,env=test_env,workspace=test_job_name,area=test_area,test-suite=test_name,build-id=test_build_no,test-name=test_uc_no,step-index=1,step-execution-time=1,step-error-message=No message,test-result=1 1572915987025'
```

But when I execute the above curl command, I get the following error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: f9084cf7-ecf0-11ea-811c-000d3ab37764
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'test_aggregate,processor=name,env=test_env,workspace=test_job_name,area=test_area,test-suite=test_name,build-id=test_build_no,test-name=test_uc_no,step-index=1,step-execution-time=1,step-error-message=No message,test-result=1 1572915987025': invalid field format
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.8.2
X-Request-Id: f9084cf7-ecf0-11ea-811c-000d3ab37764
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 07:50:30 GMT
Content-Length: 315
```

Where am I going wrong in syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the data format is wrong,

The data should be in line format,
measurement1,tag1=value1,tag2=value2 field1=value1, field2=value2 timestamp

Explanation:
measurement_name followed by comma and list of tags (comma separated), then a **space** followed by fields (comma separated) and again a **space** followed by timestamp with the right precision

Note: Space acts as a separator between tags, fields, and timestamp

In your case there are couple of mistakes,

1. you have set time precision to s (seconds) but the timestamp has 13 digits, it should have only 10 digits
2. there should be atleast one field present but your data has no fields
3. step-error-message=No message => space should be escaped with backslash (No\ Message)

Correct curl command will look like

```sh
curl -i -X POST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=test_db_local&amp;precision=s" --header "Authorization: Token maha:jhda  sdaak" --data-binary 'test_aggregate,processor=name,env=test_env,workspace=test_job_name,area=test_area,test-suite=test_name,build-id=test_build_no,test-name=test_uc_no,step-index=1,step-execution-time=1,step-error-message=No\ message,test-result=1 field1=0 1572915987'
```

I have given a dummy field called field1 with 0 value for example, you can move some tags to fields if needed

Comment: Hello Tamil Selvan,

can you please let me know what I am missing here

echo -e “usage,host=influxdb,cluster=louis,pl_instance_name=2i-retegas,gitlabusage=“Thu Oct 20 13:48:02 2022”,jenkinsusage=“Fri Jan 20 06:52:05 2023”,sonarqubeusage=“Mon Oct 17 11:52:20 2022”,nexususage=“Not Use 00 00:00:00 0000” lastused=averagetime” | curl -X POST --data-binary @- https://influxdb-.com/write?db=usage

I tried to escape space but no luck